# How to copy a sheet in one workbook to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, the first is FIRST with the sheet Sheet1, the second is SECOND with the sheet Sheet2.

In Sheet1, the data has the following format, a comma represents a new column:

```
Name, Date, Cost
Y, 03 Nov 22, 100
X, 04 Nov 22, 1000
Z, 04 Nov 22, 10000000
```

I am trying to copy specific data points from the rows in Sheet1 with today's date.
I am trying to append the Date and Name for all of today's rows to the end of Sheet2.

In Sheet2, the data has the following format, a comma represents a new column:

```
Leave blank, Date, Leave blank, Name
None, 03 Jan 18, None, A
```

I want to append to Sheet2 leaving it with the following data:

```
Leave blank, Date, Leave blank, Name
None, 03 Jan 18, None, A
None, 04 Nov 22, None, X
None, 04 Nov 22, None, Z
```

```vb
Public Sub CopyData()
    Dim data As Workbook 'Where all data is stored ie FIRST with Sheet1
    Dim destination As Workbook 'Where the days data will be appnded to ie Second with Sheet2

    Set destination = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set data = "S:..FIRST.xlsm"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure on what you want the structure/format to be, but below is code to open another workbook and copy over a worksheet in that workbook.

```
Sub CopySheet() 

Dim this_workbook As Workbook 'Declare variable of current workbook
Dim taget_workbook As Workbook 'Declare variable of the targeted workbook you want to open

Set this_workbook = ThisWorkbook

Set target_workbook = Workbooks.Open("T:\Excel\Files\Workbook2.xls") 'Opens the workbook you wish to copy data from 

target_workbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Your workbook is open, copy over the worksheet you want to copy over, in this case "Sheet2" will be copied and placed after "Sheet1"

target_workbook.Close 'Close targeted workbook

Set target_workbook = Nothing
Set this_workbook = Nothing
```

You would add this to your workbook with Sheet1 worksheet, it will open the excel workbook with Sheet2 and copy over that worksheet to your workbook.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me get a start, I'm hoping to run the macro from the SECOND workbook and reads Sheet1 from the FIRST workbook without opening it. This should help me get started

Comment: @danielstafford That's good! I wasn't sure what you wanted after as personally I prefer seeing the excel screenshots, but aye that's good! Feel free to upvote

Comment: Would you mind checking out the updated question? I have used your answer but struggling on taking the entire table from one sheet in a workbook to another sheet in a different workbook without opening the first workbook that has the data being copied into the other workbook. Clearly this is only the start of the solution but would be a great help.

Comment: @danielstafford what's wrong with opening it? I could be wrong but I don't think you can copy data without opening the file.